# Zest Linked Nodes (2 or more source nodes connected to 1 destination)

Tags: eclipse, zest

I am trying to use the Eclipse Zest Visualization Toolkit to create a graph with 5 different connections.

The 5 connections are outlined in the following paper (Fig 3. Common basic argument structures) - http://www.mit.edu/~irahwan/docs/JWS2008.pdf

Out of the box Zest can create 4 out of the 5 connections i am looking. (All except ii - linked)

I am looking for pointers how to create this connection?

In theory I want to select multiple nodes as the sources, and draw the connection (one connection) to the destination node.

Should I extend the EntityConnectionData object to take a list of sources. Then implement IConnectionStyleProvider, and modify the getRouter() to return my own custom Connection Router?

Thanks in advance,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

Create your own content provider.

1. If your input consists of elements that are connected, use `IGraphEntityContentProvider`. You will notice that with the help of `getConnectedTo`, you can return the children of the passed entity.
2. If your input consists of connections between elements, use `IGraphEntityRelationshipContentProvider`. There, you will receive each connection in the `getSource` and `getDestination` APIs.

No need to extend `EntityConnectionData`.